# Fatal error: Class 'JLayoutHelper' not found in joomala

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

Please anyone help me on this.

I'm just a beginner with Joomla.

Just started to create a category blog when I click on the blog page an error is occuring.

Below is the error I'm getting:

```
Fatal error: Class 'JLayoutHelper' not found in E:\Joomla_3.0.3-Stable-Full_Package\templates\jsn_epic_free\html\com_content\category\blog_item.php on line 29
```

Can anybody provide some help with this?

Comment: It's a problem with your template ([like here](http://www.joomlashine.com/forum/66-jsn-boot/104439-jsn-boot-jlayouthelper-not-found) or [here](http://www.joomlashine.com/forum/53-free-product-support/104526-jsn-sky)) . If it's not a major design issue try a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks from your file structure, that you're using Joomla 3.0.3

This error should disappear if you instead download and start with the latest version of Joomla, 3.2.2